# How do i add .txt on the end of a user's input?

Tags: python

I need to add `.txt` at the end of the users input but I'm unsure it has to be put on the end of the input at `[q]` is to finish my assignment.

```
FF = input("What Would You Like To Save Your Encription As?: "[q])
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what is that `[q]` for? if q is a number with that you are printing the q-th character of the prompt, to ask for a input, that is not very helpful...

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
FF = input("What Would You Like To Save Your Encription As?: ")
FF = FF + ".txt"
```

Comment: one liner: `input(...)+".txt"`

Comment: this was great thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You could also use format:

```
FF = input("What Would You Like To Save Your Encription As?: ")
FF1 = '{0}.txt'.format(FF)
```